# Laravel Method Does not Exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I can't echo the getTotal in the Cart Model

http://laravel.io/bin/VPMad#12,32,44,51

Comment: please post your code and be more specific.

Comment: You need to add code here, not a link. And unless I'm missing something, the code you linked to doesn't even have a `getTotal` method. Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you say that you're calling a method `getTotal()`, but there's no such method in the code sample you're linking to. I'm going to assume that you meant `getPrice()`.

If a user has many carts, you can't get a single one with just `$user->cart`, since that will contain the `Collection` of all of the user's carts.

If you want to show the total for each cart a user has, you could rename the method to `carts()` and do e.g.

```
@foreach ($user->carts as $cart)
    {{ $cart->getPrice() }}
@endforeach
```

Otherwise, you'll get the error you mention in your topic.

Comment: I see. How can I get the total price of all product in the price and just echo it into the view?